# How to display decimal numbers in Java?

Tags: java, android

I'm using float to display decimal numbers, but sometimes it doesn't display correct result.

For example, for 6.2/1000 the result is 0.0061999997.

I know why is this happening, but I wonder is there a way to display correct result, in this case, 0.0062?

EDIT:
[How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java) does not answer to my question, so why did you marked my question as already been answered in other place?

Numbers I wrote are only example. In the app user can enter any number and divide / multiply number with any other number, so the result maybe won't have any decimal points, maybe it will have 4 decimals, maybe it will have 7 decimals,...

Comment: Use DecimalFormat http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: Yes, use rounding. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Comment: You might need `BigDecimal` if you need arbitrary precision.

Comment: This is not a duplicate!

Answer (score 7):

First, you need to understand that this isn't just a *display* issue - if you want to avoid displaying incorrect values, it helps to *have* the right values to start with.

You should use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead of `float`. That stores the value as an integer scaled by a factor of 10<sup>exp</sup> rather than the 2<sup>exp</sup> used by `double` and `float`.

If the `BigDecimal.toString` doesn't format the result the way you want, use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to perform the formatting instead.

Answer (score 0):

Format the decimal places use this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(decimalPlace);
        String formatedValue = df.format(value);
```

Hope this will resolve your query.